# Validation loss doesn't decrease (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, loss, overfitting-underfitting

first of all, sorry for my english,

I am facing a problem with my project using tensorflow, i have to code a dictionnary (english-->german), i know it is not easy to figure out where is the problem :/ it is killing me, i am here for any question.
THANKS

The inputs:

1. En_input:

has shape of (16, 14, 128) :

-batch
-number of words (1<words<13) and using a function to map over the datasets that pads each English sequence of embeddings with some distinct padding value before the sequence, so that each sequence is length 13

```py
    def pad_eng_embeddings(data):
        def pad_eng_embeddings_(x,y):  
            return (tf.pad(x, [tf.math.maximum([13-tf.shape(x)[0] ,0],   tf.constant([0,0])),tf.constant([0,0])], "CONSTANT", constant_values=0), y)
        return data.map(pad_eng_embeddings_)
```

128 after the

```py
embedding_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128-with-normalization/1",output_shape=[128], input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
```

2. Input_german

shape (16,14)  with "**< start>**" and "**< end>**" token to the beginning and end

Problem with the Validation loss :

```
Epoch : 1 --> Loss train :  1.4463926553726196  --> Loss Validation :  1.1669453382492065
Epoch : 2 --> Loss train :  0.9627977609634399  --> Loss Validation :  0.9346983432769775
Epoch : 3 --> Loss train :  0.6962901949882507  --> Loss Validation :  0.8172098994255066
Epoch : 4 --> Loss train :  0.4979133903980255  --> Loss Validation :  0.7540919184684753
Epoch : 5 --> Loss train :  0.34379565715789795  --> Loss Validation :  0.7045937776565552
.
.
.
.
.
Epoch : 111 --> Loss train :  0.0012935919221490622  --> Loss Validation :  0.43797847628593445
Epoch : 112 --> Loss train :  0.0010554787004366517  --> Loss Validation :  0.4402512311935425
Epoch : 113 --> Loss train :  0.001183984917588532  --> Loss Validation :  0.4351470470428467
Epoch : 114 --> Loss train :  0.0008711100090295076  --> Loss Validation :  0.43835172057151794
Epoch : 115 --> Loss train :  0.0008662969921715558  --> Loss Validation :  0.4418365955352783
Epoch : 116 --> Loss train :  0.0015571219846606255  --> Loss Validation :  0.4526227116584778
Epoch : 117 --> Loss train :  0.002025176538154483  --> Loss Validation :  0.442545086145401
Epoch : 118 --> Loss train :  0.0014257029397413135  --> Loss Validation :  0.43709230422973633
Epoch : 119 --> Loss train :  0.0010628846939653158  --> Loss Validation :  0.43659183382987976
Epoch : 120 --> Loss train :  0.0008744939113967121  --> Loss Validation :  0.44265955686569214
```

Here mon code:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')
@tf.function
def loss_function(real, pred):
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
    loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)
    #print(loss_[0])
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
    loss_ *= mask
    #print(loss_[0])
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)

@tf.function
def Inputs_model(Input_german):
    return (tf.cast(Input_german[:,0:-1],tf.float32),tf.cast(Input_german[:,1:],tf.float32))
    

@tf.function
def grad(En_input,GR_input,GR_output):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        state_h_En,state_c_En = model(En_input)
        de_tensor = tf.squeeze(tf.convert_to_tensor(GR_input))
        lstm_decoder, state_h_decoder, state_c_decoder=decoder(de_tensor,state_h_En, state_c_En)
        loss_value = loss_function(GR_output, lstm_decoder)
        variables = model.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables
        gradients=tape.gradient(loss_value,variables)
    return loss_value,gradients


@tf.function
def train_step(En_input, Input_german):
  GR_input,GR_output=Inputs_model(Input_german)

  loss_value,gradients=grad(En_input,GR_input,GR_output)
  variables = model.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,variables))
  return loss_value

@tf.function
def validation_step(En_input, Input_german):
  GR_input,GR_output=Inputs_model(Input_german)
  state_h_En,state_c_En = model(En_input)
  de_tensor = tf.squeeze(tf.convert_to_tensor(GR_input))
  lstm_decoder, state_h_decoder, state_c_decoder=decoder(de_tensor,state_h_En, state_c_En)
  loss_value = loss_function(GR_output, lstm_decoder)
  return loss_value
  
 def train( num_epochs, dataset_train,dataset_valid):
    train_loss_results=[]
    validation_loss_results=[]
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      mean_loss_t=tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
      mean_loss_v=tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

      for  En_input, Input_german in dataset_train:
        loss_value=train_step(En_input, Input_german)
        mean_loss_t(loss_value)
      train_loss_results.append(mean_loss_t.result())
      
      
      for  En_input, Input_german in dataset_valid:
        loss_value=validation_step(En_input, Input_german)
        mean_loss_v(loss_value)
      validation_loss_results.append(mean_loss_v.result()) 

      dataset_train.shuffle(2)
      dataset_valid.shuffle(2)
      #checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
      print("Epoch :",epoch+1,"--> Loss train : ",float(train_loss_results[epoch])," --> Loss Validation : ",float(validation_loss_results[epoch]))
      if float(validation_loss_results[epoch])< 0.02:
        return train_loss_results, validation_loss_results
    return train_loss_results, validation_loss_results
```

Comment: How large is your dataset? Did you try to decrease your learning rate?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer: train Dataset= 1000*16 (batch) . do you think learning_rate=0.0001 will be better ?

Comment: So one epoch just contains 1000 batches? Yes, I would defintely try that, since you are clearly overfitting. What I did in cases like that was at first pretraining with a higher training rate and later reducing it.

Comment: yes for one epoch i have 1000 batch, i don't know how to reduce the number or batch for every epoch, like : epoch 1 --> 1 to 15 , epoch 2 --> 16 to 30

Comment: sorry I didnt't mean to say you should modify the batch size during training but instead start a train session like you currently do, but with fewer epochs (Aproximatly shortly before the epoch number you are currently starting to overfit now). Then use this model to start another training session with a reduced learning rate and more epochs and check if your results improve.